# How to explain that an object at a certain point with zero velocity can move away from that point by having an acceleration?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

As A.P.French points out:

> You may feel, . . . , that we have gone to excessive lengths in our discussion of instantaneous velocity & acceleration. But make no mistake about it; these are very subtle concepts. The notion that an object could both be at a certain point and moving past that point was one that perplexed some of the best minds of antiquity.. . . . If you want to test your mastery of these ideas of instantaneous velocity & acceleration,try **explaining to someone how an object that is at a certain point with zero velocity can nonetheless move away from that point by virtue of having an acceleration.** It really isn't trivial.

Now, how can I explain this?

Comment: I don't see the problem. Motion is due to velocity, velocity is due to acceleration, acceleration is due to force. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @glance: Sir, doesn't velocity exist even if there is no acceleration? So how "velocity is due to acceleration"?

Comment: velocity may exist without acceleration, but it cannot change without it. So acceleration causes *change* in velocity, which is what we are dealing with here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Throwing a ball**

Throw a ball upwards. It will start falling down again at some point. That is a point, where it has exactly **zero velocity**.

At that point the **acceleration** (due to gravity) is **non-zero**. If it wasn't, the ball would stay at zero velocity. But the ball only stop, so it can speed up again (downwards) and move away from the point again in the next instant of time. That is because of acceleration.

---

**A pendulum**

Watching a pendulum swinging back and forth, it has **zero velocity** in both ends of the curve. Exactly at the point where it changes direction.

Here the **acceleration is the greatest**, and will cause the pendulum to move away from the point, by increasing its velocity in the next instant of time.

---

Are these examples the explanations you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

This is [Zeno's arrow paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes) in disguise.

We write acceleration as:

$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt} $$

where $dv$ and $dt$ are [infinitesimals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitesimal). So assuming constant acceleration the velocity is given by:

$$ v = \int_0^t adt $$

In other words we compute the infinitesimal velocity changes $adt$, and we add them all up to give a finite value for $v$. This is where the ancient Greeks fell over because they didn't understand calculus. Zeno's arrow paradox comes down to if $adt$ is infinitely small then how can you add up any number of infinitely small things to get a finite result?

If you're asking how to explain this to the non-mathematically sophisticated then I don't think there is an answer. To be honest I don't understand the mathematician's approach to this myself. The best I can do is to note that if $adt$ is small but finite then we add up $n$ of them to approximate the velocity:

$$ v \approx n \times adt $$

As we reduce $adt$ and increase $n$ the approximation gets better and better, and in the limit of $adt \rightarrow 0$ and $n \rightarrow \infty$ it becomes exact.

Comment: +1. Indeed sir,you are right. On a quite different basis, the uncertainty principle expresses our inability to measure both the position & the velocity precisely.

Comment: @user36790 The uncertainty principle expresses our inability to measure both position and *momentum* precisely. If you consider a mass larger than at the atomic scale (a car, a ball, a pendulum, even a grain of sand), then this is of *no* influence.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is dealing with infinitesimal quantities try discretizing the equation.

Let's assume for simplicity a constant force $F$ on an object of mass $m$, at rest for $t \le t_0$ for some $t_0$, and discretize the time in intervals of length $\epsilon/2$ for some small $\epsilon$.

Newton's equation in this discretized form reads$^\dagger$:
$$ \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}(t_0) = \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \left[ x(t+\epsilon)-2x(t)+x(t-\epsilon)\right] = \frac{F}{m}.$$
Now if the object is at rest for $t \le t_0$ this becomes
$$ x(t+\epsilon) = \epsilon^2 \frac{F}{m}.$$
And you can here safely go for the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.

---

$^\dagger$ This comes from the definition of the derivatives. You have
$$ \frac{dx}{dt}(t_0) \equiv \frac{1}{\epsilon} [ x(t_0+\epsilon/2)-x(t_0-\epsilon/2) ],$$
and deriving again
$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2}(t_0) \equiv \frac{1}{\epsilon} \left[ \frac{dx}{dt}(t_0+\epsilon/2) - \frac{dx}{dt}(t_0-\epsilon/2) \right]
= \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \left[ x(t+\epsilon)-2x(t)+x(t-\epsilon)\right] . $$